# Accepting and routing http requests over raw TCP socket

Tags: http, go, tcp, server

I am building a web server that must accept HTTP requests from a client, but must also accept requests over a raw TCP socket from peers.  Since HTTP runs over TCP, I am trying to route the HTTP requests by the TCP server rather than running two separate services.

Is there an easy way to read in the data with net.Conn.Read(), determine if it is an HTTP GET/POST request and pass it off to the built in HTTP handler or Gorilla mux?  Right now my code looks like this and I am building the http routing logic myself:

```
func ListenConn() {
    listen, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    defer listen.Close()
    for {
        conn, err := listen.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            logger.Println("listener.go", "ListenConn", err.Error())
        }
        go HandleConn(conn)
    }
}

func HandleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()

    // determines if it is an http request

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        ln := scanner.Bytes()
        fmt.Println(ln)
        if strings.Fields(string(ln))[0] == "GET" {
            http.GetRegistrationCode(conn, strings.Fields(string(ln))[1])
            return
        }

        ... raw tcp handler code

    }
}
```

Comment: Implement a [net.Listener](https://godoc.org/net#Listener) that peeks at first line of data in Accept method.  Create net.Conn with Read method that stitches together peeked data and data from the underlying net.Conn.  Return this net.Conn if first message is HTTP request, otherwise pass to your other handler.  Use the listener in call to http.Serve or one of its friends.

Comment: This is going to cause a lot of headaches and introduce a ton of additional complexity. Is there any particular reason you can't just expose the TCP wire protocol and HTTP on separate ports?

Comment: `bufio.Reader` has a [`Peek`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio?tab=doc#Reader.Peek) method, which how one normally inspects part of a stream, but as @Adrian said, is there really that compelling of a reason to add this complexity when separate ports suffices for nearly every other use case?

Comment: It would be simpler, but it would also be inconvenient for an administrator and redundant.  I already have other services running and would like to limit them as best as possible.  @Adrian

Comment: @jacobr I am uncertain about what you mean by running two separate services, but note that a single application instance can listen on multiple ports.

Comment: Listening on two ports should not be "inconvenient for an administrator and redundant". Many, many, many services listen on multiple ports. We're not talking about multiple *services* here. One service, multiple ports.

Comment: Don't just don't. Listen on two ports, handle this separately. What you're trying to do is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to mix HTTP and raw TCP traffic.

Think about all firewalls and routers between your application and clients. They all designed to enable safe HTTP(s) delivery. What they will do with your tcp traffic coming to the same port as valid HTTP?

As a solution you can split your traffic to two different ports in the same application.

With ports separation you can route your HTTP and TCP traffic independently and configure appropriate network security for every channel.

Sample code to listen for 2 different ports:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type httpHandler struct {
}

func (m *httpHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("HTTP request")
}

func main() {
    // http
    go func() {
        http.ListenAndServe(":8001", &httpHandler{})
    }()

    // tcp
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8002")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer l.Close()
    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}

// Handles incoming requests.
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    // read/write from connection

    fmt.Println("TCP connection")
    conn.Close()
}
```

open `http://localhost:8001/` in browser and run command line `echo -n "test" | nc localhost 8002` to test listeners

Comment: I'm not aware of any router that would care what you send inside your TCP packets - in fact most of them won't care that it's TCP at all aside from potentially using ports for route selection. L7-aware firewalls that verify HTTP requests are also pretty rare in my experience, and the ones I know of require explicit opt-in ("this port is HTTP").


Note that for most intermediate network devices, all they will usually see is TLS traffic - and even if they wanted they couldn't distinguish if what you're sending is HTTP or whatever else.